# How to fix Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined

Tags: nuxt.js

I get an error when I want to send the value from the API results to the data, the error is like this

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'notification' of undefined at eval (HeaderPortal.vue?070f:367)
```

this my `HeaderPortal.vue`

```
data() {
  return {
    notification: []
  }
}

mounted: {
  const res = this.GET('/api/v2/notification', 'BEARER', null).then(function(res) {
     console.log(JSON.parse(res))
     this.notification = JSON.parse(res);
  });
}
```

this.GET comes from here

```
methods: {
  async GET(url, headers, callback) {
    const options = headers === 'BASIC' ? HEADERS_BASIC : HEADERS_BEARER;
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}${url}`, options);
      return (JSON.stringify(response));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

how to handle it? is there something wrong in my code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to access the `this` keyword, make sure you use arrow functions `() => {}` instead of regular functions `function() {}` in your callback. If you don't, the `this` keyword will be `undefined` in your case. This is why you get an error trying to set `this.notification = JSON.parse(res);` in your first code snippet.

*Your first code snippet is a bit weird, maybe you forgot to copy something? You code should not be directly inside the methods object. It should be in the mounted hook, or in a proper method like in the second snippet.*

Answer (score 1):

answer up is low clear , let me show what do with example :

```
data() {
      return {
        notification: []
      }
    }
    methods: {
        const res = this.GET('/api/v2/notification', 'BEARER', null).then( res =>  {
          console.log(JSON.parse(res))
          this.notification = JSON.parse(res);
        });
    }
```

i hope  be useful

Answer (score -1):

`this` in the inner function refers to the function only, therefore it is not working. Instead, write:

```
s=this;
const res = this.GET('/api/v2/notification', 'BEARER', null).then( 
function(res) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(res))
      s.notification = JSON.parse(res);
    });
}
```

Comment: Does this add anything new to the previous answer from almost a year ago?

Comment: yes , to an extent , because  how 'this' should be changed was addressed in the new answer